# how can I find the angle measures in a three-rhombus triple

Tags: geometry

I understand the properties of rhombuses and that two angles must be 60 degrees and the other two must be 120 degrees to form 360 degrees. However, I'm not sure at all how to solve this question, or what it's even asking.

[image]

and how would this differ from finding the angle in a two-rhombus pair such as

[image]

Any help is appreciated, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

The task is to find the angles of all rhombuses. And to find these angles it's enough to find the acute angle of each rhombus. In the 3-rhombus problem you have three different ones: $\alpha_1$, $\alpha_2$ and $\alpha_3$

Just by adding angles to get a full circle, you have the following set of equations (one per picture):

$$\alpha_1 + 3\alpha_2 +5\alpha_3=360^\circ$$

$$2\alpha_1 + 5\alpha_2 +2\alpha_3=360^\circ$$

$$\alpha_1 + 10\alpha_2 +\alpha_3=360^\circ$$

Solve this system of equations and you are done.

The second problem is even simpler. You have two different rhombuses, two different angles and a system of two equations.

Comment: Thanks so much! I’d never seen a question worded like this before so I was confused but now it makes complete sense!